# How to fetch dynamically rendered HTML from a SPA

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, single-page-application, fetch-api

#### Context

I'm trying to use the javascript fetch command to return the HTML of a leetcode.com webpage, but when I do the returned HTML is in a pre-rendered state i.e. the div of interest is empty:

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

When I load the page of interest with my browser and inspect element however, I can see that this "app" div gets populated with dynamic content as leetcode uses single-page-application technology. This rendering must be happening after the fetch command executes.

#### Question

I would like to know how to use the fetch command *or similar* in order to retrieve the html of a fully rendered webpage. I would like to do this to scrape some content which only appears after the webpage has been fully rendered.

#### Assumptions

I'm assuming that the fetch command cannot return html that gets rendered by javascript, i.e. similar to what you'll find with vue.js or react.js

Comment: fetch doesn't render pages.

Comment: Do you know how I could use javascript to return the rendered html?

Comment: Don't use JS. Instead you'll likely need to use a headless browser tool like puppeteer or playwright.

Comment: Yes I've seen puppeteer mentioned on similar problems. I'll need to try and get it working within a chrome extension but thanks for the suggestion!